# ¿El sitemap debería tener las URLs amigables para mejorar el SEO?

Tags: seo, pretty-urls, sitemap

Estoy generando el sitemap a través de PHP, ya que quiero controlar las URLs que se indexan, pero tengo una duda, puesto que antes no usaba URLs amigables y ahora sí.

Es decir por ejemplo tengo esta estructura:

```html
<url>
  <loc>http://www.miweb.com/contacto.php</loc>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

¿Debería modificarla a esta?

```html
<url>
  <loc>http://www.miweb.com/contacto/</loc>
  <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

Es decir, cambiar `contacto.php` por `/contacto/`. Tenía pensado pasarlo todo ya para que apareciese con URLs amigables, que entiendo será mejor para los robots de Google para entender qué hay en la URL.

Comment: Creo que si tienes bien puesta la meta información en la página de destino, a los motores de búsqueda no les va a importar que url uses en el sitemap. Lo único que quieren es que enlaces las páginas existentes para indexarlas... pero tendría que mirar la documentación para comprobar que no te estoy diciendo una burrada

Comment: Por cierto, casi te diría que cambiaras el etiquetado de la pregunta. No es sobre PHP, sino sobre sitemap, SEO y herramientas de webmaster (es más lenguaje agnóstico)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Gracias, entiendo que si lo pongo con las URLs amigables no habrá problema. No sé exactamente como coge Google la información de las URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tenía pensado pasarlo todo ya para que apareciese con URLs amigables, que entiendo será mejor para los robots de Google para entender qué hay en la URL

Esto es un concepto erróneo. **Las URLs amigables son amigables para los humanos**. A los ordenadores/máquinas/robots de Google les es indiferente qué sean fáciles de leer por humanos y "no ven diferencia" entre `/contacto.php` o `/contacto/`.

Si tienes bien puesta la meta información en la página de destino, a los motores de búsqueda no les va a importar que URL uses en el sitemap*; lo único que quieren es que enlaces las páginas existentes para indexarlas.

Si tienes una página que puede accederse de diferentes maneras, lo que debes hacer es especificar cuál de las URLs es la canónica. Entonces, no importa cuál de las versiones de la URL visite el robot de Google, se indexará con la URL especificada como canónica.

Por ejemplo, tienes `/contacto.php` o `/contacto/`, pero quieres que Google la indexe como `/contacto/`, entonces deberías añadir el siguiente código en la cabecera de tu página:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://misitio.com/contacto/" />
```

De este modo, cuando se rastree tu sitio web, independientemente de la URL que tengas puesta en el sitemap, Google indexará la página como `/contacto/`. En este [artículo de Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=es) puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo funciona.

---

*Si no se especifica una URL canónica, puede que el motor de búsqueda indexe la página con la URL enlazada en el sitemap. De hecho,
 en la página enlazada arriba, [en la sección sobre sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=es#3), se recomienda usar la que vas a usar como canónica. Pero no se garantiza que vayan a usar esa URL.

Answer (score -1):

Además de lo ya añadido por el compañero, comentarte que con el `sitemap` no controlarás de ninguna manera lo que *Google* indexa o deja de indexar un sitio, porque *Google* rastrea *URLs* estén o no en el mapa del sitio siempre que no se indique lo contrario. Si quieres evitar la indexación de determinadas páginas y controlar el *crawl budget* hazlo a través del **robots.txt**.